# How to get entrie ID in the spreadsheet page source

Tags: android

The spreadsheet url:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HEvFwx10XIMa4ZH6CuQzHFInuCgosaNzttMzU8sMnyg/formResponse
The id of the name column: entry.188672219
The id of the cat question column: entry.1859048068.

they say it is in the view page source but iam not abel to find the id of the perticular column.

Comment: I want to post the data from my app to the spreadsheet using google forms plz help me out if there are any other way to do it .

Comment: Your question is not explained at all, you didn't post any code and we cannot see what you already did to resolve your problem. I really wonder who upvoted your post.

Comment: The link does not point to a spreadsheet. It is completely unclear what you ask. Data from which app?

Comment: I actually wanted to post the data from my android app to the google spreadsheet to a particular column or row through spreadsheet column and row id.

Answer (score 1):

Update- The question refers to this tutorial http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/tut-send-app-data-to-a-web-spreadsheet-google-sheets/

Answer - In the tutorial it is explained how to use Google Forms to update excel in Google Drive from an Android app. Please refer to the tutorial & source code is available at https://github.com/blundell/SpreadsheetInputTut.